# how to find failed logins from a port or application?

Tags: centos, security, logs, users, login

I have a Virtual Machine with CentOS 7 as OS and a database is installed on this server. there are users like `dbuser` for database administrators . They can login to server via ssh and has complete access to database and all of its tables and objects. There are other users that belong to developers and they have limited access to database. These users are defined with `nologin`:

```
  useradd -c 'Developer - Robert Benton' -M -s /sbin/nologin devbenton
```

They use applications that connects to database. A connection definition in those applications are like this:

```
     Database Name: TestDB
     IP: 192.123.1.1
     Port: 6500
     Username: devbenton
     Password: ********
```

Recently we found out that someone found a user's password with a loop by guessing and trying to login so many times. the options are to block the IP with firewall or use something like `Fail2ban` to block users and IPs after failed logins.

How to find out that users are doing something like that? In `/var/log/secure` or other log files i can't see failed login from users that use an application. I want to monitor my system but how i can do that?

Comment: That depends on the DB. For example Mysql: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30525/saving-every-mysql-user-login-attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/var/log/secure` only tracks failed **shell** logins. Since you want to monitor users whose shell access is disabled (as specified by the `-s /sbin/nologin` argument in `useradd`) and that try to log in to a certain application, you will need to check the logfiles of that application. Whether this is possible, how to do that, and which files to examine depend on the application.

Note also that "failed logins from a port" doesn't mean anything. What you mean is failed network logins on an application, which is served on a specific port on the server.